# Symfony2 - Callback validator on collection

Tags: symfony, validation

In symfony2 I'm tying to use a callback to validate my form, but this callback is never called. The class wherein the callback is, is called in the main form through a collection.

Here is my code...

Main class :

```
class InscriptionType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('inscriptionReponses','collection',array('label'=>false,
                                                           'type'=>new InscriptionReponseType(),
                                                           'error_bubbling'=>false,
                                                           'by_reference'=>false))
        ;
    }
}
```

InscriptionReponse class :

```
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\ExecutionContextInterface;

/**
 * InscriptionReponse
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Ptolemee\ColloqueBundle\Entity\InscriptionReponseRepository")
 * @Assert\Callback(methods={"formValidation"})
 */

class InscriptionReponse
{

    /* ... some code ... */

    public function formValidation(ExecutionContextInterface $context)
    {   
        die('not dying ?');
    }    

}
```

I don't understand what's wrong... any help would be highly appreciated. tahnks.

Nicolas.

Answer (score 1):

The callback function of the collection is being called when you add @Assert\Valid to the collection in the containing entity.

Let's say Inscription has a collection of InscriptionResponses:

```
class Inscription
{
    /**
    * @Assert\Valid()
    */
    private $inscriptionResponses;
}

class InscriptionResponse
{
    /**
    * @Assert\Callback
    */
    public function formValidation(ExecutionContextInterface $context)
    {   
        die('dying');
    }  
}
```

This works regardless of the value of the error_bubbling option.

Answer (score 0):

base on what is written in the documentation:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Callback.html

instead of

```
/**
* @Assert\Callback(methods={"formValidation"})
 */

class InscriptionReponse
{
```

you should move the annotation above the function itself

```
class InscriptionReponse
{

/**
* @Assert\Callback
 */
    public function formValidation(ExecutionContextInterface $context)
    {   
        die('not dying ?');
    }
```

The method you used was valid in version 2.3, you use 2.4 probably now

Comment: Hello, thanks for yo answer... indeed, i use 2.4, and so i mvoved the annotation. But it's still not working... never passing in the callback...

Comment: try setting the form option: 'error_bubbling'=>true